# Code coverage test with BullsEye

Tags: c, code-coverage, bullseye

I am using Bullseye for code coverage test with some C code.
I successfully instrumented my c code with Bullseye. Then I tried to disassemble it to see what's in there.

I was expecting that there should be some probe function inserted at `every control transfer location`. Such as `for`, `if`, `while`, etc. But to my surprise, I only see `a single probe at the the beginning of each of my functions`. Such as this one:

[image]

So how could this single probe trace all the control transfers?

And when I view the collected coverage data, all my control-transfers are recorded as not covered. Only the function entry point is rocorded as covered.

Did I mis-configure the Bullseye so the above screenshot is only coarse `function coverage`? If so, how can I configure Bullseye for fine-grained control-transfer-based coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

The instrumented code looks like this:

```
#pragma bss_seg(push,".covbss")
static struct cov_V_d934b203 cov_v_d934b203;
#pragma bss_seg(pop)
#pragma const_seg(push,".covconst")
static const struct cov_O_d934b203 cov_o_d934b203 = {
0x5a6b7c8d, 0x6b54972d, &cov_v_d934b203, 0x254972d, cov_V_d934b203_n, "CpuPeimTest.obj 21Apr18 22:20"
};
```

...

```
if(!cov_v_d934b203.data[0])cov_probe_v11(&cov_o_d934b203,0);{ // this is right after the function entry.


 do { if (DebugPrintEnabled ()) { do { if (DebugPrintLevelEnabled (0x80000000)) { DebugPrint (0x80000000,"Ming: Code coverage test start.\n"); } } while (((BOOLEAN)(0==1))); } } while (((BOOLEAN)(0==1)));
```

So essentially, it stored some coverage data collector objects, `cov_c_xxx` and `cov_v_xxx`, in the `.covconst` and `.covbss` segments respectively. And at runtime, the instrumented code log data points to `cov_v_xxx` object.

The `cov_probe_v11` invoking *at the function entry* just link the `cov_c_xxx` and `cov_v_xxx` into the final result link list. The `cov_probe_v11` is part of the Bullseye runtime lib. You can modify it to adapt to your code under test.

**Once linked**, all the *other* data collection can happen without the need to invoke the `cov_probe_v11`.

Comment: How did you get hold of the instrumented code? Which location on disk does it get written to?

Comment: `covc.exe` when used with `-l` option generates the temporary instrumented code in `%temp%/covc/<file_id>/file.cpp`. see `https://www.bullseye.com/help/ref-covc.html`. Found answer to my own question while going through bullseye doc.